# DiffableDataSource throws "Fatal: supplied identifiers are not unique." when wrapping MPMediaItem inside a struct

Tags: ios, swift, diffabledatasource

I used `UITableviewDiffableDataSource` with `UITableView` to display songs from the music library. This code worked fine:

```swift
let tracks: [MPMediaItem] = MPMediaQuery.songs().items ?? []
self.dataSource.apply(section: 0, items: tracks)
```

But when I wrapped `MPMediaItem` inside a custom `Track struct`, I got this error: `Fatal: supplied identifiers are not unique.`

```swift
struct Track: Equatable, Hashable {
  let item: MPMediaItem

  var title: String? { item.title }

  init(item: MPMediaItem) {
    self.item = item
  }
}
let items = MPMediaQuery.songs().items ?? []
let tracks: [Track] = items.map { Track(item: $0) }
self.dataSource.apply(section: 0, items: tracks)
```

`MPMediaItem` has already conformed `Equatable` and `Hashable` so I think it should be fine if I use it in another struct which also conforms `Equatable` and `Hashable` (`Track struct`).

Update 1: `apply(section:items:)` is an extension I added to `UITableViewDiffableDataSource` for convenient:

```swift
extension UITableViewDiffableDataSource {
  func apply(section: SectionIdentifierType, items: [ItemIdentifierType], animatingDifferences: Bool = false) {
    var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<SectionIdentifierType, ItemIdentifierType>()
    snapshot.appendSections([section])
    snapshot.appendItems(items)
    apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: animatingDifferences)
  }
}
```

Update 2: It worked after I conformed `Track` to `Identifiable` protocol:

```swift
struct Track: Equatable, Hashable, Identifiable {
  let item: MPMediaItem

  let id: MPMediaEntityPersistentID

  var title: String? { item.title }

  init(item: MPMediaItem) {
    self.item = item
    self.id = item.persistentID
  }
}
```

or even changed `title` to store property also worked without any errors:

```swift
struct Track: Equatable, Hashable {
  let item: MPMediaItem

  let title: String?

  init(item: MPMediaItem) {
    self.item = item
    self.title = item.title
  }
}
```

What makes it so different between these cases? And why do I got the error when using `MPMediaItem` as the only store property of the `Track` struct? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about that. I have updated my question. Thanks!

Comment: Okay now I’m intrigued. What if you omit the title property entirely?

Comment: Hi @matt, I have updated my question again with two solutions that worked. But I don't know why only use `MPMediaItem` as store property without any other store property like `id` and `title` threw the error.

Comment: You should confirm the hashable by hasher function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to guess that there's a bug in MPMediaItem's hashability. This can cause you to get different answers for the two situations you have described. In this example, I'll deliberately make a buggy NSObject:

```
class Dog : NSObject {
    let name : String?
    init(name:String?) {self.name = name}
    override func isEqual(_ object: Any?) -> Bool {
        if let dog = object as? Dog {
            return self.name == dog.name
        }
        return false
    }
}

struct DogHolder : Hashable {
    let dog : Dog
    var name : String? { dog.name }
}
```

Here's a test:

```
    var set = Set<DogHolder>()
    let dh1 = DogHolder(dog:Dog(name:"rover"))
    let dh2 = DogHolder(dog:Dog(name:"rover"))
    set.insert(dh1)
    set.insert(dh2)
    print(set.count)

    do {
        var set = Set<Dog>()
        let dh1 = Dog(name:"rover")
        let dh2 = Dog(name:"rover")
        set.insert(dh1)
        set.insert(dh2)
        print(set.count)
    }
```

Run the test over and over. Sometimes I get 1 and 2. Sometimes I get 2 and 1. Sometimes I get 1 and 1. Sometimes I crash.

I don't know what the precise problem is, but evidently exposing the NSObject hashability to Swift's hashability requirements exposes the bug. I would suggest reporting this to Apple and meanwhile continue to use a workaround such as your identifier.

Comment: The default `hash` implementation of `NSObject` uses the object's pointer value. Therefore, if you override `isEqual` to check equality based on the data members, you must override  `hash` as well, otherwise you'll be violating the requirement that `A == B → hash(A) == hash(B)`.
Maybe Apple engineers did the same mistake when overriding `isEqual` for `MPMediaItem`.

Comment: @TamásZahola Good theory; I did think of something like this, of course, but whatever it is, I can't prove it.